# Prolog Family Tree query issues

Tags: prolog

```
% facts
mother(john, dana).
father(john, david).
mother(chelsea, dana).
father(chelsea, david).
mother(jared, dana).
father(jared, david).
% queries
father(X,Y) :- father(X,Y), write(Y). 
mother(X,Y) :- mother(X,Y), write(Y).
parent(X,Y) :- father(X,Y);mother(X,Y).
sibling(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z), parent(Y,Z), write(Y).
```

I am having trouble getting these queries to work. when I type in the father command, it will tell me yes or no correctly, but won't do the write command (same with mother). "parent" doesn't work at all for me (therefor sibling doesn't either). Also, if I type in sibling(X,Y). I need to get all siblings...for example, sibling(john, chelsea). I need to output all the possible siblings (jared as well). Let me know where I am going wrong, I really don't see an issue with my logic here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can remove your mother and father predicates that are not facts. They are infinite loops. Since parent use them and sibling use parent, all your predicates are infinite loops.

To see what happens, you can do that :

```
?- trace, father(john, X).
```

and observe how prolog handles the query. You'll soon observe than to resolve father, he needs to solve father, and that to solve father, he needs to solve father, and that it never stops...

When the two problematic are removed, I obtain a correct behaviour :

```
?- father(john, X).
X = david.

?- parent(john, X).
X = david ;
X = dana.

?- sibling(john, X).
john
X = john ;
chelsea
X = chelsea ;
jared
X = jared ;
john
X = john ;
chelsea
X = chelsea ;
jared
X = jared.
```

Now, to make your sibling predicate better, you could say that someone is not its own sibling and that if you have one common parent it's enough (it will remove the duplicates) :
sibling(X,Y) :- father(Y,Z), father(X, Z), X =\= Y.

Comment: Thanks Mog. Didn't realize that I had to accept questions, I thought it was based on voting. I will definitely do that for this particular question and from now on. I understand what you're saying. This is my first PROLOG program, so I apologize for the simplicity of my questions. I got rid of the father and mother queries. Parent seems to now work OK. My parent clause still seems to not be working however, and you didn't address the sibling question I asked at the end. Can you help me with that? Thanks

Comment: I edited a bit my answer, I advise that you play around the mother and father queries to start, by asking with free and bound variables (X or john for example) so that you see how prolog uses predicates. Don't hesitate to ask if something is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been incredibly helpful.

Comment: Perhaps this is because of my version of gprolog...but when I type in parent(john, X). as you have,  I don't get X = david ; X = dana, I only get X = david . What could be a possible problem for that?