# GNUProlog only returns one of the values for a query

Tags: prolog

```
% facts
mother(john, dana).
father(john, david).
mother(chelsea, dana).
father(chelsea, david).
mother(jared, dana).
father(jared, david).
% queries
parent(X,Y) :- father(X,Y);mother(X,Y).
```

When I type in "parent(john, X).", I get X = dana, but not X== david. However, on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394117/prolog-family-tree-query-issues), the person who responded to me seems to get both parents. Is this a limitation of gprolog or am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: does it return X=dana first? that's weird.  btw you should get warnings like this in gnu-prolog: "warning: discontiguous predicate mother/2 - clause ignored"; that's because the clauses of mother/2 (and father/2) are not grouped together so gnu-prolog ignores them (at least vs1.3)

Comment: thanos, how do I fix this issue? -edit- do I need to write all the mothers in a row, then all the fathers in a row?

Comment: yup, write every clause of the predicate under the other ( mother(john, dana). mother(chelsea,dana). etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all the results you have to press the semicolon key `;`, once for each solution.

If you want to get all the results as a list, you can try

```
?- findall(X, parent(john, X), L).

L = [david,dana]
```

Comment: Thanks gusbro.  I didn't catch the semicolon. Is there anyway to make my association automatically report all values?

Comment: The ; is a typical prolog convention used in the top-level (where you are doing your queries). If you want to print all the solutions you can write a simple procedure that binds the result, prints it and then fails to get the next solution.

Comment: Thanks gusbro. Can you recommend a good resource for doing this? I'm having a lot of trouble finding resources for prolog online.

Comment: You can do it with the builtin forall/2 predicate: `forall(parent(john, X), (write(X), nl)).`. Also search in this site for prolog reference books. There are some questions here that address these.

Answer (score 2):

In the interactive top-level query answering loop you get
a next solution by typing the semicolon ";".

Your example works fine in GNU Prolog:

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.0
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2011 Daniel Diaz
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
mother(john, dana).
father(john, david).
parent(X,Y) :- father(X,Y);mother(X,Y).

user compiled, 4 lines read - 725 bytes written, 33109 ms

(2 ms) yes
| ?- parent(john,X).

X = david ? ;

X = dana

yes
```

Bye